# What is the difference between enthalpy and internal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

What is $pV$ in enthalpy's equation? If we transfer energy to a system in the form of work, does it reflect in its internal energy fully? If it does, why do we need a term called “*enthalpy*” which separates $pV$ term in its equation? If $pV$ is not included in internal energy, then why does the internal energy of the system changes upon doing work?

Comment: Enthalpy is not a fundamental quantity like internal energy is.  It is just a convenient function to work with in solving many different types of problems.  I have seen others try to assign a physical significance to enthalpy, but, in my judgment, their efforts were futile, and their descriptions were highly contrived (and unconvincing).  My advice to you is to not spend your valuable time with this, and instead focus on getting practice solving problems in which enthalpy comes into play.  In short, enthalpy is no more and no less than H=U+PV.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Sorry, I pasted this before seeing your comment which basically says the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Enthalpy is a state property and is defined as

$$H=U+pV$$

where $H$ is the enthalpy, $U$ is the internal energy, and $pV$ is the product of pressure and volume. So enthalpy is a state property derived from internal energy and other properties, $p$ and $V$.

Enthalpy is simply a useful derived property for analyzing certain type of thermodynamic problems. It is not a fundamental property such as internal energy, entropy, pressure, volume and temperature.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As noted correctly above, enthalpy is just the sum of the internal energy and $PV$,
\begin{gather*}
H = E+PV
\end{gather*}
More formally, it is a Legendre transform of the internal energy that gives a new thermodynamic state function that depends on a new set of natural variables. To see why, we can use the fundamental thermodynamic relation of the internal energy written as,
\begin{gather*}
dE = TdS - PdV + \sum_j \mu_j dn_j
\end{gather*}
which tells us that the internal energy is a natural function of the entropy, volume, and the number of moles of each species. By taking the differential of $H$ and expanding out, we obtain,
\begin{align*}
dH &= dE + PdV + VdP \\
&= TdS - PdV + \sum_j \mu_j dn_j + PdV + VdP \\
&= TdS + VdP + \sum_j \mu_j dn_j
\end{align*}
which tells us that the enthalpy is a natural function of the entropy, pressure, and the number of moles of each species. Furthermore, if we consider the case where the pressure and number of moles of each species is constant, we can use the Clausius entropy $dS = \frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T}$ to find a more intuitive picture of the enthalpy,
\begin{align*}
dH &= TdS \\
&= T \frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T} \\
&= \delta q_{rev}\\
\implies \Delta H &= q &&\text{(constant }P, \{n_j\}) 
\end{align*}
In other words, the enthalpy can be interpreted as the amount of heat that a thermodynamic process exchanges under conditions of constant pressure and a for fixed amount of substance.

Edit to respond to edits: the reason that the internal energy responds to work is because the 1st law explicitly relates the changes in internal energy to work and heat transferred in a process. This manifests primarily in the fundamental relation in that the internal energy is a function of volume. As I noted above, the enthalpy is useful both because it gives a state function of different natural variables than internal energy and because of its intuitive connection to heat transfer at constant pressure (a typical condition of many chemical experiments).